# Verilog questions on 2's complement and left roate

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a 16 bits ALU with verilog.
My inputs are 16 bits Ain,Bin and 16 bits output out.

I am required to do a 2's complement addition and subtraction of both inputs. As such I am wondering if I can just use the '+' and '-' operator. `Ain+Bin`, `Ain-Bin`

Also, I am required to do a left rotate of the bits in A by a certain value N. I came out with the following where I replicate A to form 32 bits and shift it to the left by N bits. But now the problem is I am required to reduce it to 16 bits again but how can I do that?

`out <=({A,A}<<N);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `+-` operators if you want to add or subtract two numbers.

If you want to truncate the result back to 16 bits, just assign the result to a 16 bit wire/register, and it will automatically drop the upper bits and just assign the lower 16 bits to `out`. In some cases this may create a lint warning, so you may want to assign the result to an intermediate variable first, and then do an explicit part select.

```
wire [15:0] out;
wire [15:0] A;
wire [31:0] A_rotate;

A_rotate = {A,A} << N;
out = A_rotate[15:0];
```

Comment: ok so example if A=4'b1110, `{A,A}`=11101110. So shifting it left by 2 bits will end up with 10111000. So if I assign this value to 4 bits out, out=4b'1000 or 4b'1011?

Comment: It takes the lower 4 bits, so out will be 'b1000.

Comment: So if I want to obtain the upper bits I will have to use an intermediate and then `out = A_rotate [31:16]`? actually is there a way to do it in a single step without an intermediate like `out<=({A,A}<<N)[31:16]`

Comment: You can't part-select the result of an expression. If you really wanted to get the upper 16 bits without an intermediate variable, you could shift the whole thing right by 16 bits, such that the upper bits moves into the lower bits (`out <= ({A,A}<<N)>>16 `). This is a bit clunky though and might be more readable by using two steps.